# What was Jane's catchphrase?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

At the end of *Thor: Love and Thunder* Jane whispers her latest and greatest catchphrase idea to Thor who pronounces it 'perfect'.

What was the catchphrase?

> [image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqVCT.png

Comment: "Love and Thunder"?

Comment: *"It's clobberin' time"*

Comment: All right then, keep your secret.

Comment: Stop, hammer time?

Comment: Valhalla calling?

Comment: Kick cancer before it kicks you,   or Hey cancer you picked the wrong bitch?

Answer (score 8):

### Natalie Portman

In an interview, Portman states that she did say something to Hemsworth, but intends to keep it a secret.

> ...at the end of my time with Natalie Portman that our conversation veered into spoiler territory. Asking about Jane Foster’s final whisper to Thor, I inquired both if it was a specific line and about the experience on set, and Portman said, *"Yeah, that scene was really, really fun to shoot, and **yes, [there is a specific line, but I will never reveal it](https://youtu.be/ISLkK2HTn7k?t=211)**.*"
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Love And Thunder: What Did Jane Foster Whisper To Thor? Natalie Portman Discusses The Secret](https://www.cinemablend.com/interviews/thor-love-and-thunder-what-did-jane-foster-whisper-to-thor-natalie-portman-discusses-the-secret)</sup></sub>

---

### Taika Waikiti

Waikiti has been customarily jokey about the line and refuses to commit to a serious answer.

> **Throughout the movie Jane is trying to come up with a cool catchphrase for herself. At the end there's a great moment where Jane whispers her Mighty Thor catchphrase to Thor. We don't hear it. Is there actually a catchphrase?**
>
> **TW:** *It's like, does Bill Murray ever really say anything to Scarlett Johansson in "Lost in Translation"?*
>
> **The moment is very much a hat tip to "Lost in Translation."**
>
> **TW:** *Even when we were shooting it we were like, "Yeah, we're just taking this from 'Lost in Translation.'" But, I don't know what she said. I would like to think it's something like, "Your ass is still mine."* [Laughs.] *"Your ass will always be mine."*
>
> <sub><sup>['Thor: Love and Thunder' director shares what he thinks Natalie Portman whispered to Chris Hemsworth in their final scene together](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/thor-love-thunder-director-shares-150001430.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: "... but intends to keep it a secret." All right then. Sorry, I couldn't resist.